# How to specify a height for footer using bootstrap in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am creating a website using WordPress and Bootstrap.

1) How to include the custom style sheet I created in my footer.php?

2) How to specify distance between the different components, if they are in different rows or containers?

I am adding the style withing the html divs for now. On the picture you can see the components. I have 4 rows i.e. Logo, social, mini navigation and copyright. How to decrease the distance between the social icons the the Connect with us text?

[Have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOhpo.png)

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div id="mydiv" >
   <div class="container-fluid p-3 p-md-5" "my-custom-class" >
      <footer class="container-fluid"  style="margin-top: 30px; > 
         <div class="row" >
         <div class="text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4" ><img src="<?php echo 
               get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/footer_logo.png"></div>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Connect with us<p>
   <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?
      >/img/fb.png">
   <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?
      >/img/tw.png">
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Conditions</a>
   <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">In the press</a>
   <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Privacy</a>
   <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Cookie Consent</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"  >© wwwwww, 2004-2017.</div>
   </div>
   </footer>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class ( space for example) to each row and add your style in your footer css file.

modifications in footer.php :

```
<div class="row space">
```

in your style file you add :

```
.space {
    margin-bottom : 25px ;
}
```

Comment: Can I add the .space style between style tag withing the php file? And what part this will effect? Because I am adding it but does show any changes

Comment: Yes you can add it in your footer.php, its will affect only the rows which have space as class in your footer.php file